# Javascript files adding root path to links

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, aws, php-5.6

I have created an instance on AWS and installed a LAMP stack on it as per their tutorials and installed an existing magento site on to it.

I pointed my local hosts file at the new server, cleared the var folder (including the cache) and the site loaded. Great!

But none of my Javascript files were loading. Not a single one, so I looked at the URLs they were trying to load from and it's done something very strange.

It has added the path to the root directory **after** the domain like so:

https://example.com/{pathtoroot}/media/js/myfiles.js

Causing the 403 forbidden error on every js file. CSS files and images which use the same root URL as per the magento config are loading perfectly.

URL rewrites are working fine, and if I try to access the correct link directly, it loads the file. I've tried messing about with the root urls but found nothing works and the site works on another (cPanel) server.

I'm sure I'm missing a server setting somewhere, but I've been playing around for ages and found nothing.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: UPDATE: In the source it is not adding the domain src="/var/www/html/js/prototype/validation.js"

Comment: Today I encountered the same issue. The issue was missing media folder.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/121464)

Answer (score 3):

Today I encountered the same issue. The issue was missing media folder.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/121464)

Comment: @roshi, please  write little bit about solution.So, that other can understand the anwer

Comment: @RamaChandranM, Sorry We have undo this  delete of this question as  we are getting some meaningful for  this post.Any way thanks for continuation

Comment: @AmitBera i wish i can edit your comment ;)

Comment: ha ha.... you can do oneday:)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data media/ var/
rm -rf var/cache/* && rm -rf var/session/*
```

Worked perfectly for me.